# При клике по dismissalText в Snackbar создается новый экземпляр Window

Tags: c#, maui

Начал изучать MAUI и столкнулся с такой проблемой: при клике по клавише отмены в Snackbar создается новый экземпляр приложения в Windows, на андроид все работает корректно.

```
private async void OnCreate(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CancellationTokenSource cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var message = "Учетная запись создана";
    var dismissalText = "Кликни чтоб закрыть уведомление";
    TimeSpan duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);

    Action dismissAction = async () =>
        await DisplayAlert("это action", "Пользователь отказался", "OK");

    var snackbarOptions = new SnackbarOptions()
    {
        BackgroundColor = Colors.Yellow,
        TextColor = Colors.Black,
        CornerRadius = new CornerRadius(20),

    };

    var snackbar = Snackbar.Make(message, dismissAction, dismissalText, duration, snackbarOptions);

    await snackbar.Show();

    vm.ActivityIndicatorIsRunning = false;
}
```